# How to dispose Spring RedisTemplate safely?

Tags: redis, jedis, spring-data-redis

I have to create RedisTemplate for each of the requests (write/read) on demand.
The connectionfactory is JedisConnectionFactory

```
JedisConnectionFactory factory=new 
    JedisConnectionFactory(RedisSentinelConfiguration,JedisPoolConfig);
```

Once, I do operations with RedisTemplate.opsForHash/opsForValue, how to dispose the templates safely , so that the connection is returned to JedisPool.

As of now , I do this with

```
template.getConnectionFactory().getConnection().close();
```

Is this the right way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RedisTemplate` fetches the connection from the `RedisConnectionFactory` and asserts that it is returned to the pool, or closed properly after command execution, depending on the configuration provided. (see: [JedisConnection#close()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/v1.4.2.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/jedis/JedisConnection.java#L239))

Closing the connection manually via `getConnectionFactory().getConnection().close();` would fetch a fresh connection and close it right away.

So if you want to have a bit more control, you could fetch the connection, perform some operations and close it later

```
RedisConnection connection = template.getConnectionFactory().getConnection();
connection... // call ops as required
connection.close();
```

or use `RedisTemplate.execute(...)` along with `RedisCallback`, so that you do not have to worry about fetching and returning the connection.

```
template.execute(new RedisCallback<Void>() {

  @Override
  public Void doInRedis(RedisConnection connection) throws DataAccessException {
    connection... // call ops as required
    return null;
  }});
```

Comment: I do operations only with opsForHash/opsForValue/execute. So I dont have explicity close the connection ?

Comment: I was facing exceptions while fetching connections from the pool. I thought it might be because of RedisTemplate not being destroyed /disposed properly. Now I am not facing that connection issue.I have removed the line as you have answered.